# Replace value in str

Tags: php

I have an array of values and a string:

```
$arr = array('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
```

I have also a string that may have one of the values present in the array, although it may be capitalized differently.

```
$str = 'Masasd asdsd Bbb asdasdas...';
```

I need to evaluate the string and if the match is found, of a value in the array to a value in the string, I need to make the one in the string in all caps. Having difficulty putting it together.

Do I split the string and evaluate each value?... Seems like there should be a better way.

```
if (in_array('Bbb', $arr)) {
    echo strtoupper('Bbb');
}
```

Desired result:

```
$str = 'Masasd asdsd BBB asdasdas...';
```

Comment: Please include your code so far so we can see where you are up to, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: I don't have code. I'm trying to figure out how to do it first. Seems like it's obvious to down-voters, although they failed to provide any suggestions... Is stackoverflow now immuned to "obvious" oversight or there are so many snobs around?..

Comment: Well the general view is that by including at least some code it shows you've made an effort, rather than expecting to be spoon-fed the answer. That said, I didn't think your question was bad enough to be down-voted. But then I'm relatively new around here, so maybe I'm the one who's wrong...

Comment: Maybe that should be made a requirement when a question is posted?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) to replace case insensitive in a string.

In your case:

**EDIT**: even better without loop and now your array can contain also lowercase:

```
<?php
    $str= str_ireplace($arr, array_map('strtoupper',$arr) , $str);
?>
```

(asssuming all values in `$arr` are upper case as in your example)

Adding a fix according to Mark's note:

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $value){
        $str= str_ireplace(' '.$value.' ', ' '.strtoupper($value).' ' , $str);
    }
?>
```

(You can also loop `$arr` and add spaces before and after each word then run it as in the first example)

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. I was actually leaning towards eval()

Comment: EVAL IS EVIL! don't use it unless you really really really need to

Comment: oops... Yes, the array is all caps. Lemme give it a try.

Comment: Note that this will match any occurrence of the array items in the string, not only whole words.

Comment: @MarkParnell you are right however we can easily add a space before and after each value :) Thanks for heads up

Comment: That will then not match the words at the start and end of the string. Or any that are next to punctuation.

Comment: It's be always in the middle of the string.

Comment: @santa Then this is definitely what you are looking for :)

Comment: Wait, but the value in the string is capitalized differently than in the array. Is this case insensitive? How does it find it in the string?

Comment: @santa this is case **insensitive**, all you have to take care about is that your array values are in upper case as in you're example

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this, just a different approach:

```
$values = explode(' ', $str);
$lower = array_map('strtolower', $values);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
  if ($key = array_search(strtolower($value), $lower)) {
    $values[$key] = $value;
  }
}
$str = implode(' ', $values);
```

Comment: But yes, `str_ireplace` is the right way to go :-)

Comment: I think what you have here is the direction I was considering. Thanks.